# mailx and HP-UX to RedHat migration

Tags: linux, shell-script, hp-ux, migration

We are migrating some servers from HP-UX to Linux RedHat, and we have to migrate about 100 shell scripts that are referencing /usr/bin/mailx (instead of /bin/mailx on Linux).

We'd like to change all the 100 scripts (from /usr/bin/mailx to /bin/mailx) only if this is the last option.

Are there better ways of doing this?

P.S.: our system administrators don't want to create a symbolic lynk "/usr/bin/mailx" pointing to /bin/mailx (I didn't understand why, actually).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solution that came to my mind 5 minutes ago (ugly but probably effective): in .profile -> alias "/usr/bin/mailx"="/bin/mailx"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the sysadmin would like to use the alternatives system instead of just plunking a symlink into /usr/bin:

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/mailx mailx /bin/mailx 10
```

This essentially does this:

```
/usr/bin/mailx -> /etc/alternatives/mailx
/etc/alternatives/mailx -> /bin/mailx
```

It's more complicated, so therefore it might be better ;)

Comment: Didn't know of "alternatives". What's the purpose of this command? It acts very similarly to a symbolic link...

Comment: It's a symbolic link manager, basically. It allows you to install different versions of tools (such as java) and easily control which one is "visible"

Comment: I read in the manual there are Red Hat specific options. Is that manager only available to Debian based distributions?

Comment: Nope, redhat has it.